# Cannot execute binary file when calling Java from Bash

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

There are 4 files involved: 'compile.sh', 'execute.sh', 'work.c', 'tester.sh'.

In 'compile.sh', it compiles the 'work.c' file and outputs an executable file called 'execute.sh'. In my own testing process, I do `./compile.sh`, then `./execute.sh` to run my C program. This works.

Now, the 'tester.sh' is a script that calls a Java program and this Java program does the same thing. It will run my 'compile.sh' first and then excute 'execute.sh'. It checks the correctness of my program outputs.
The problem is that when I do `./tester.sh`, I get the error below

> Reading first line from program...
>
> ./execute.sh: ./execute.sh: cannot execute binary file
>
> First line of execution should match: Created \d heaps of sizes .+
>
> Failed to execute (error executing ./execute.sh)

You can ignore the third line "First line of execution...."; it tries to check whether my output matches exactly with the tester. Since the binary file cannot be executed, then the first line does not match for sure.
So why does it say "cannot execute binary file"?

Content in compile.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -Wall work.c -o execute.sh
```

Content in tester.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

java -cp bin/tester.jar edu.ssu.cs153.work1.Tester
```

(bin/tester.jar is in my local machine; we can assume there is nothing wrong with the tester script.)

Comment: Using `.sh` as the extension of a binary file is... odd to say the least. What does `file execute.sh` say? Can you run `execute.sh` by hand? Are you sure that should be a binary file and not a script that runs your binary file?

Comment: Rather hard to tell. Show us the (presumable Java) code that tries to execute `./execute.sh` - perhaps there's code somewhere that assumes this is a  shell script based on the .sh extension. And make sure it tries to run the execute.sh file you think it does, and not some other file located elsewhere in the file system.

Comment: file execute.sh is just an ouput file from compiling work.c file. It is just like a.out by default from gcc. I can run ./execute.sh from the terminal and see all the correct outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

It is weird, but not disallowed, to name an executable with the .sh extension. Your problem is that the Java code is trying to run it as a shell script (e.g. `bash ./execute.sh`), and it isn't a shell script so it fails. You need to change the Java to run the `.sh` file as an executable instead of as a shell script. Or, better (since you probably can't fix the Java), fix the compilation so that it produces an executable with a different name (e.g. `work`), and have `execute.sh` execute `./work`.

> File `execute.sh` is just an output file from compiling the `work.c` file. It is just like `a.out` by default from `gcc`. I can run `./execute.sh` from the terminal and see all the correct outputs.

The trouble is, when you run it, you do `./execute.sh` and the shell executes directly. The Java is running it as `bash ./execute.sh`, and that generates the error. Try it at the command line.

#### Prescription

On the face of it, you need to change `compile.sh`, perhaps like this (generating a program `work` from `work.c`):

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -o work -Wall work.c
```

And you write a shell script called `executable.sh` that reads:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec ./work "$@"
```

This script runs your program with any command line arguments it is given.  The `exec` means the shell replaces itself with your program; there are minor advantages to doing it that way, though it'll be OK if you omit the `exec` from the script.

Comment: It works now. You got to the point.  execute.sh should contain scripts. Thanks